# Python: SOAP response. Delete the Response header, keep the rest?

Tags: python, web-services, csv, soap

I think this is simple.....

I have a script that takes a bunch of data, changes some characters, splits the data into columns and rows with headers and outputs as a CSV. This worked perfectly fine in testing with the data coming in from a text file. The real use is calling to an authenticated webservice. Which also works fine.

The issue is all the code that formats the data and makes the final CSV file doesn't work when it's called from the webservice.

The reason is the very first line of the results

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><env:Header></env:Header><env:Body><ns1:GetACustomReportResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.customurlfortesting.com/gem/services/gds">< report >Header1,Header2,Header3
```

When I was testing initially, I just retrieved Header1,Header2,Header3 etc all seperated by a character thats replaceable. The same is still true now, but the rest of the formatting is failing at the beginning because of the stuff before the Header1. Is there a way to simply not get that info in the results?

```
r = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
data = str(r.text.encode('utf-8').replace("\"....etc  < im guessing I can strip that first line of the reults in here since this is where my results are but I don't exactly how to remove that line dynamically without affecting anything else. I want to remove everything from <env:Envelope to <report> including <env:Envelope and <report>
```

Thanks

Comment: Question not very clear, can you expand on the specific issue? Are you using a specific SOAP library or just the `requests` module?

Comment: @Cahit added some more detail in the original post. let me know if its still not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it sorted

added to the initial string definition

```
.rpartition('<report>')[-1]
```